# Variable values in For Each loop being retained

Tags: vbscript

I'm new to VBScript and I am running into some trouble. The script is making an API call and pulling account information, placing the data into a `CSV` file. I'm pulling the data into an array, looping through each account and, if certain properties qualify, assigning them to a variable to be written to the `CSV`. The problem I am having is if one account qualifies for a property, it sets the variable and if the next account doesn't qualify, the variable is still retaining the value, giving false results in the `CSV`.

```
Set SFTPServer = WScript.CreateObject("SFTPCOMInterface.CIServer")
accounts = SFTPServer.AdminAccounts
For each admin in accounts
  adminName = admin.Login

  Dim count : count = admin.GetPermissionsCount()
  For i = 0 To CInt(count )- 1
    Set permission = admin.GetPermission(i)

'    AdminPermissionsPolicy:
'        ServerManagement = 0,
'        SiteManagement = 1,
'        STManagement = 2,
'        UserCreation = 3,
'        ChangePassword = 4,
'        COMManagement = 5,
'        ReportManagement = 6,


    Select case permission.Permission
      case 0:
        serverAdmin = "Server Admin"
      case 1:
        site = permission.SiteName
      case 2:
        stMan = "2"
      case 3:
        userCreate = "3"
      case 4:
        chPassword = "4"
      case 5:
        comMan = "5"
      case 6:
        report = "6"
    End Select
    Next

    WriteStuff.WriteLine""+adminName+"|"+site+"|"+stMan+"|"+userCreate+"|"+chPassword+"|"+comMan+"|"+report+"")
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately variables in VBScript are either at global, or function scope.

So you'll need to reset each of the variables on each iteration of the `for` loop.

One way would be to write `Dim dummy` at the top of your script, and just before the `Select Case`, write `serverAdmin = dummy`, `site = dummy` etc.

It's good practice to `Dim` explicitly all your variables, and to use `Option Explicit` at the top of the module to enforce that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate way to do what you need without having to empty each variable on each iteration. You've already documented what each value means in your code. Instead of using comments for that purpose, define them as constants at the top of your scope block:

```
' AdminPermissionsPolicy:
Const ServerManagement = 0
Const SiteManagement   = 1
Const STManagement     = 2
Const UserCreation     = 3
Const ChangePassword   = 4
Const COMManagement    = 5
Const ReportManagement = 6
```

Then you can declare an array to hold the values:

```
Dim a(6)
```

And then in your loop you can empty the array on each iteration using the `Erase` function. You can use the constant names instead of `0/1/2/etc` and, when it comes time to write the values, you can use `Join()` to combine your array values into a string instead of having to concatenate 7 variables.

```
For each admin in accounts

    adminName = admin.Login
    Erase a                    ' Empty the Permissions array for each new account

    Dim count : count = admin.GetPermissionsCount()
    For i = 0 To CInt(count )- 1

        Set permission = admin.GetPermission(i)

        Select case permission.Permission
            case ServerManagement:    ' Now you can use the constant instead of "0"
                a(ServerManagement) = "Server Admin"
            case SiteManagement:
                a(SiteManagement) = permission.SiteName
            ...
        End Select
    Next

    WriteStuff.WriteLine Join(a, "|")  ' Use Join() to combine array values

Next
```

Comment: Thanks Bond! This almost has what I want. I still need to add the adminName to the output. I tried adding it to the array but if the first case qualifies it replaces the admin name with server admin. The desired output should look like adminName|server admin|siteName|...

Comment: You could make it part of the array but it would screw up our array index values so it's probably easier to just add it to your output separately: `WriteStuff.WriteLine adminName & "|" & Join(a, "|")`

Comment: That got it. I was trying this solution as well but didn't have the right syntax. Thanks for your help Bond!

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the output. You want to print a list of items (some of them possibly Empty) separated by "|". That should be done like this:

```
WriteStuff.WriteLine Join(aOut, "|")
```

Advantages:

1. You don't need to know that VBScript's concatenation operator is `&`, not `+`, because you can't even use the wrong one with Join.
2. You don't need to repeat the separator.
3. No useless pre/ap-pending of the empty string "".
4. Works with any number of items.

`aOut` needs to be initalized in the loop. That is easy with [ReDim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c850dt17%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) - without Preserve.

Advantages:

1. You don't need to know that Empty is the literal for empty/uninitialzed in VBScript.
2. You don't need to repeat an assignment for each variable.
3. Works with any number of items.

Demo code:

```
Option Explicit

Const cnUB = 3

Dim nTest
For nTest = 0 To cnUB
    ReDim aOut(cnUB)
    Select Case nTest
      Case 0
        aOut(0) = "A"
      Case 1
        aOut(1) = "B"
      Case 2
        aOut(2) = "C"
      Case 3
        aOut(3) = "D"
    End Select
    WScript.Echo Join(aOut, "|")
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 31565794.vbs
A|||
|B||
||C|
|||D
```

Disadvantage:

1. Putting the data into the array anonymously (just known by number/index) may be more errorprone than using distinct variable( name)s. If you need the elements for further computations it may be a good idea to define constants

wtf

```
Const ciReport = 1
...
aOut(ciReport) = "B"
```